# python TypeError: 'crm.lead.product' object cannot be interpreted as an integer, Odoo 14

Tags: python, odoo

'lead_product_ids' consist of a list of products and I am trying to multiply qty*price unit of each product to get the total and then add all totals.

**error**:
TypeError: 'crm.lead.product' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

**Code**

```
 @api.depends('lead_product_ids.qty', 'lead_product_ids.price_unit', 'lead_product_ids')
    def _compute_total_price(self):
        for rec in self:
            for i in rec.lead_product_ids:
                for all in range(i):
                    total = (all.qty * all.price_unit)
                    rec.total_qty_price_unit = sum(total) or 0
```

Comment: @holydragon. If I change it, I get this error --> TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

@api.depends('lead_product_ids.qty', 'lead_product_ids.price_unit', 'lead_product_ids')
    def _compute_total_price(self):
        for rec in self:
            for i in rec.lead_product_ids:
                total = sum(i.qty * i.price_unit)
                rec.total_qty_price_unit = total

Comment: Can you please add info about the model definition behind `lead_product_ids`?

Comment: @CZoellner  I did get the answer and I have edited what holydragon did come up with.
Thanks though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like

```
for i in rec.lead_product_ids:
```

is assigning `i` as a product for each of the products in `lead_product_ids`.

So, when you do

```
for all in range(i):
```

It will try to do `range()` of `i` but `range()` expects an integer input -- not a product object, hence the error

> TypeError: 'crm.lead.product' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

To solve this, you should use `i` instead.

```
@api.depends('lead_product_ids.qty', 'lead_product_ids.price_unit', 'lead_product_ids')
def _compute_total_price(self):
    for rec in self:
        for i in rec.lead_product_ids:
            total = (i.qty * i.price_unit)
            rec.total_qty_price_unit += total
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer but it is giving this error:
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

Comment: @Jaymezon Can you specify the line where the error occurs?

Comment: line 19, in _compute_total_price
    rec.total_qty_price_unit = sum(total) or 0

Comment: @Jaymezon I see. I didn't look into the issue about using sum(). It won't work like that. See my edited answer.

Comment: It is working well and giving me the sum but not correct ones e.g the value given by rec.total_qty_price_unit += total is not correct. e.g (1x7) + (10x10) = 107 but it is giving a different answer which is higher than 107.

Comment: @Jaymezon That issue is not in the scope of this question. There are many factors in your system that can cause the issue including this method. By only seeing this part of the code, I cannot help solving the latest issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking your time to respond and for the answer.
If I change it to -->  total = sum(i.qty * i.price_unit) and rec.total_qty_price_unit = total.
It gives this error --> TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238915/discussion-between-jaymezon-and-holydragon).